# Django POST method is not receiving all input fields from HTML

Tags: python, html, django, post, request

please I would like to ask for help. I'm creating a web-based application and I'm having a hard time when I try to get the data from the HTML form and receive it through the POST method in Django.
It's pulling data only from one field and I really appreciate your help in figuring out why it's not pulling information from the other fields only from the **location field**. Thank you very much!

```
HTML = create-request.html

        <form action="{% url 'save_request' %}" id="checklistForm" name="checklistForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <section id="step-1" class="form-step">
            <div class="mt-3">
              {% include 'home/1_resource-request.html' %}
            </div>
          </section>
        </form>
```

```
HTML = home/1_resource-request.html

{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %} {% block content %}

<div class="pcoded-content">
  <div class="pcoded-inner-content">
    <div class="main-body">
      <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h5>Resource Request</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="checklistID">Checklist Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checklistID" name="checklistnum" placeholder="123456" disabled/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="location_ID">CMPA Location</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="location_ID" name="location">
                          <option selected>Select</option>
                          <option>Brazil</option>
                          <option>Canada</option>
                          <option>Mexico</option>
                          <option>SSA</option>
                          <option>United States</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="support_id">CMPA Support Needed</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="support_id" name="support">
                          <option selected>Select</option>
                          <option>Both</option>
                          <option>PMA - Financial Management</option>
                          <option>PMO - Project Administration</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="band_pma_id">Band (PMA)</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="band_pma_id" name="band_pma">
                          <option selected>Select</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                          <option>7</option>
                        </select>
                        <small id="textInfo1" class="form-text text-muted">There is no B4 for US and CA - in progress.</small>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="band_pmo_id">Band (PMO)</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="band_pmo_id" name="band_pmo">
                          <option selected>Select</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                          <option>7</option>
                        </select>
                        <small id="textInfo2" class="form-text text-muted"
                          >There is no B4 for US and CA - in progress.</small
                        >
                      </div>

                      <div class="mt-3">
                        <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="2">Next</button>
                        <button class="button2 btn btn-outline-primary " type="submit">Save</button>
                      </div>

                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    {% endblock content %}
```

```
Django/Python = views.py

def save_request(request):
    #print(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = {}
        location = request.POST.get('location', None)
        support = request.POST.get('support', None)
        band_PMA = request.POST.get('bandPMA', None)
        band_PMO = request.POST.get('bandPMO', None)
        ippf = request.POST.get('ippf', None)
        print(location, support, band_PMA, band_PMO, ippf)
    return render(request, 'home/create-request.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That html defines many different forms.  The first form has the `location` input element, the second form has the `support` input element, and so on.

Only one form can be submitted at a time.  By default it is the first form on the page, so that's why you only see the `location` element.

I think you need to rewrite the html to have only one form.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have many  tags.

You need to keep only one, the one wrapping your include, so do that :

```
<form action="{% url 'save_request' %}" id="checklistForm" name="checklistForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <section id="step-1" class="form-step">
        <div class="mt-3">
          {% include 'home/1_resource-request.html' %}
        </div>
      </section>
    </form>
```

and that :

```
 HTML = home/1_resource-request.html

{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %} {% block content %}

<div class="pcoded-content">
  <div class="pcoded-inner-content">
    <div class="main-body">
      <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h5>Resource Request</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="checklistID">Checklist Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checklistID" name="checklistnum" placeholder="123456" disabled/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="location_ID">CMPA Location</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="location_ID" name="location">
                          <option selected>Select</option>
                          <option>Brazil</option>
                          <option>Canada</option>
                          <option>Mexico</option>
                          <option>SSA</option>
                          <option>United States</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="support_id">CMPA Support Needed</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="support_id" name="support">
                          <option selected>Select</option>
                          <option>Both</option>
                          <option>PMA - Financial Management</option>
                          <option>PMO - Project Administration</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="band_pma_id">Band (PMA)</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="band_pma_id" name="band_pma">
                          <option selected>Select</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                          <option>7</option>
                        </select>
                        <small id="textInfo1" class="form-text text-muted">There is no B4 for US and CA - in progress.</small>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="band_pmo_id">Band (PMO)</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="band_pmo_id" name="band_pmo">
                          <option selected>Select</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                          <option>7</option>
                        </select>
                        <small id="textInfo2" class="form-text text-muted"
                          >There is no B4 for US and CA - in progress.</small
                        >
                      </div>

                      <div class="mt-3">
                        <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="2">Next</button>
                        <button class="button2 btn btn-outline-primary " type="submit">Save</button>
                      </div>

                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    {% endblock content %}
```